# ASP.NET Can a PartialViewResult check the state of a model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my Controller I have a method which is creating a model to hold some information from a database, is there a way to create some logic within the method to check if the model already has data in it?  This `SelectCompanyFromDropdown()` is called each time the user navigates to another page, but to reduce database calls I would like to check. I am wondering if a global variable would do the trick, but i know you can get into trouble debugging globals.

```
pseudo: 
if(Model != null)
Run Method
return PartialView(new model)
Else
return PartialView(existing model)
```

Controller Method:
    public PartialViewResult SelectCompanyFromDropdown()
            {

```
            var coid = Lt.GetThisUsersCoId();
            var model = new CompanyViewModel();
            using (var dc = new CompanyViewModelDbContext())
            {
                var content =
                    (from cr in db.CompanyRelationship
                     //This is grabbing all related companies to the logged in user
                     join c in db.Companies on cr.CoId equals c.CoId
                     where cr.PartnerCoId == coid

                     select new
                     {
                         cr.CoId,
                         c.CompanyName
                     }).Distinct().ToDictionary(cr => cr.CoId, c => c.CompanyName);

                model.Companies = content;

            }
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

This is sending the model to a view to create a drop down, however I would like to just reference the existing model each time the user changes pages.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is checking for a mandatory field, which has to be filled in any case. So if Model.mandatoryField !=null, then do work...

Comment: I actually just went ahead and cached the data, then made checks for the cached object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result from your database call is not going to change quite often you could cache it. So start by writing a method that will perform this task:

```
private IDictionary<int, string> GetCompanies(int coid)
{
    var result = MemoryCache.Default[coid.ToString()] as IDictionary<int, string>;
    if (result != null)
    {
        // we already have cached results => no need to perform expensive database calls
        // we can return directly the cached results;
        return result;
    }

    // there's nothing in the cache => we need to make the DB call
    // and cache the results for subsequent use
    using (var dc = new CompanyViewModelDbContext())
    {
        result =
            (from cr in db.CompanyRelationship
             //This is grabbing all related companies to the logged in user
             join c in db.Companies on cr.CoId equals c.CoId
             where cr.PartnerCoId == coid
             select new
             {
                 cr.CoId,
                 c.CompanyName
             }).Distinct().ToDictionary(cr => cr.CoId, c => c.CompanyName);
    }

    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy
    {
        // Cache the results of the Db query for 24 hours
        AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(24),
        Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
    };

    MemoryCache.Default.Set(coid.ToString(), result, policy);

    return result;
}
```

and now all that's left in your controller action is to call this method to populate your view model:

```
var model = new CompanyViewModel();
var coid = Lt.GetThisUsersCoId();
model.Companies = GetCompanies(coid);
return PartialView(model);
```

Also you seem to have some misunderstandings about view models. Your EF context seems to be called `CompanyViewModelDbContext`. View models are classes that are specifically designed to meet the requirements of your view logic. Your data layer (which is what EF plays the role for in your case) should have absolutely no knowledge of this view logic. Your domain models should not be tied to your view models.

Comment: So what you are saying is the view model should only hold information being passed to the view? With no database logic? This is what I ended up implementing.